# View bounds on abstract parameters: a use case concerning ordering

Tags: scala

I have a family of containers, of the form

```
trait Value {
  type Internal
  implicit def order:Internal => Ordering[Internal]
  def value:Internal
}
```

I want to be able to define an ordering for a specific subtype of Value, using the ordering on the Internal type, like:

```
object Value {

  implicit def order[V <: Value]:Ordering[V] = Ordering((_:V).value)

}
```

However, the compiler says that there is no implicit ordering available for V#Internal, even though such an ordering was specified in the trait.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You need a type constraint on `Internal` to ensure that it has an `Ordering`. This is easy if you define `Value` as a `class`:

```
abstract class Value[Internal: Ordering] {
  def value: Internal
}
```

As a trait, I don't believe this is possible to apply such a constraint directly, but you can require that a suitable `Ordering` be supplied:

```
trait Value {
  type Internal
  def value: Internal
  implicit val ord: Ordering[Internal]
}
```

and use as

```
class Foo extends Value {
  type Internal = Int
  def value = 42
  implicit val ord = Ordering[Internal]  // Ordering's apply method
}
```